# Restore db in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I created a backup (`.bak`) file and transfer it to another computer when I'm trying to make backup I get an error:

> BACKUP LOG cannot be performed because there is no current database backup.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you backup the log as well as the db?

Comment: unclear what you are asking. you are taking a log backup? what about taking a database backup first? how does the transfer of the bak files comes into play? what's the content of the bak file? how you create that bak file? which sql commands you use? **PLEASE do put the details in the post and not in the comments**.

Answer (score 1):

This error is raised when you have never taken full backup of your database and  try to attempt to take backup of the log only. You need to take a full backup. If you can't find the correct options in SSMS, you can use the following script

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDB] TO DISK = N'C:\MyDB.bak'
GO
BACKUP LOG [MyDB] TO DISK = N'C:\MyDB.bak'
GO
```

Comment: I'm already tried to do this and got this errors:   
Msg 911, Level 16, State 11, Line 1
Database 'livacast' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
Msg 911, Level 16, State 10, Line 1
Database 'livacast' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP LOG is terminating abnormally.

Comment: That message suggest the database `livacast` does not exists

Comment: I know)) But it exists and my ".bak" file in c folder too

Comment: Can you add the contents of this query to your question: `select * from sys.databases where name = 'livacast'`

Comment: When I'm trying to create it again I' getting an error that it's already exists

Answer (score 1):

Take full backup first and then take log back up. The error is stating that you never took a full backup before taking a log backup.

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DBName]
TO DISK = N'C:\DBName.bak'
GO
BACKUP LOG [DBName]
TO DISK = N'C:\DBName.bak'
GO
```